# Socket Daemon Thread Does Not Stop

Tags: python, python-3.x, multithreading, sockets

I'm running this socket daemon thread on Python 3.x. From my understanding, the daemon thread should exit immediately when main thread exits. However, when I run the following code, the daemon thread stays alive. Would someone please explain this strange behavior?

```
in_queue = queue.Queue()
out_queue = queue.Queue()

def server_handler():
        conn = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
        conn.setsockopt(socket.SOL_SOCKET, socket.SO_REUSEADDR, True)
        conn.connect(("localhost", 18000))
        # set connection to non-blocking
        conn.settimeout(0)
        while True:
            try:
                msg = conn.recv(1024)
                if not msg:
                    break
                msg = pickle.loads(msg)
                in_queue.put(msg)
            except socket.error:
                while out_queue.qsize():
                    msg = out_queue.get_nowait()
                    pickled_msg = pickle.dumps(msg)
                    conn.sendall(pickled_msg)
                    # sleep
                    time.sleep(0.5)
# start thread here
threading.Thread(target = server_handler, args = (in_queue, out_queue,), daemon=True).start()
```

Comment: Indeed, this should immediately exit. Do you run it in a python REPL? In this case the main thread is waiting for your input. If you run this without REPL the process would exit as soon as the thread is launched

Comment: I tried to run on Python IDE and VS Code, same result.

Comment: try running `python3 <name_of_file>` in your shell